# Restart supervisor without stopping child processes

Tags: unix, process, supervisord

I am using [gearman](http://gearman.org/) and [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to manage my worker processes. I have a case where I need to stop/restart supervisor without affecting the currently running processes.

e.g. I have configured the `numprocs` value in supervisor conf file as 2. I start supervisor and have 2 processes running.

Now I want to restart supervisor, such that the number of processes becomes 4, where supervisor controls only the two new processes. Is there a way this can be done.

I tried renaming the `sock` file before restarting. It didn’t work. I am using Amazon Linux.

## EDIT

I will just elaborate more on what I am doing. I have some worker processes for gearman which are managed by supervisor. It works fine, but when I restart supervisor, the workers are killed and new workers are launched even if the workers are busy processing a job. So, I lose all the work done by processes.

So, I am using [php-pcntl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcntl.php) to intercept the signals produced by supervisor and then exit after the job is finished. This seems to be working well.

I send the interrupts like the following:

```
supervisorctl signal SIGTERM all
```

and then in my worker code, I have the following.

```
public static function work(GearmanWorker $gw){
        pcntl_signal(SIGTERM, function($sig){
            exit;
        });

        while(true){

            $gw->work();

            // Calls signal handlers for pending signals
            pcntl_signal_dispatch();

        }

    }
```

Now, when I update my worker code, I should restart supervisor. But, if I directly restart, then even with the above implementation, all the processes are terminated. I want to avoid terminating the old prcoesses as they will quit by themselves when `pcntl_signal_dispatch();` is called.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. supervisord is designed to control all the processes that it spawns and shut them down on exit. I sense, though, that there's something else larger you're trying to do. Can you elaborate a little? There might be a better solution.

Comment: @NoufalIbrahim 
 
I added some details about what I am trying to achieve